# how to change style of element before html rendering completely?

Tags: angular

in my instagram.component.html file i assign `boxPosition` id to my `div`. then i use that in another component which is named sidenav.component.ts. sidenav component first run and when i click in one icon in this component then instagram.component execute.

problem is here that at first before instagram component execute i use `boxPosition` element to change right-margin of that but `boxPosition` is null and i see error.

here is my instagram.component.html :

```
<div class="content-container d-rtl">

  <div class="main-rectangular d-rtl" id="boxPosition">

  </div>

</div>
```

here is my instagram.component.ts :

```
export class InstagramComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output('boxPosition') public boxPosition: ElementRef;

  constructor(public appGlobal: AppGlobals) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

here is my sidnavbar.component.html :

```
<a class="icon-calendar"
   (click)="subSideNav('content-production')"
   routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="./content/production"
   ></a>
```

and here is my sidnavbar.component.ts :

```
subSideNav(id) {
    const navProperty = document.getElementById('subTitleSideNav');
    const navWidth = window.getComputedStyle(navProperty, null).getPropertyValue('width');
    const boxProperty = document.getElementById('boxPosition');


    if (navWidth === '0px') {
      // Open sidenavbar
      document.getElementById('subTitleSideNav').style.width = '140px';
      this.titleID = id;
      console.log(boxProperty);
      document.getElementById('boxPosition').style.marginRight = '240px';

    }
}
```

box property is null so `document.getElementById('boxPosition').style.marginRight` not work.

how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: Why don't you apply the style changing logic in the `ngOnInit` of the instagram component?

Comment: my problem is before renderign instagram.component.html , my boxPosition element id is undefined and i can not change anything. if you know solution tell me. thanks.

Comment: @NabilShahid i fix this problem in `ngOnInit `. thanks

Comment: No problem. Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Updated instagram.component.ts :

```
export class InstagramComponent implements OnInit, 
 AfterViewInit{ 
  @Output('boxPosition') public   boxPosition: ElementRef;   
   constructor(public appGlobal:   AppGlobals) { } 
  ngOnInit() { } 
  ngAfterViewInit(){ 
      document.getElementById('boxPosition').
       style.marginRight = '240px';
  }
}
```

Updated sidnavbar.component.ts :

```
 subSideNav(id) { 
  const navProperty = document.getElementById('subTitleSideNav'); 
  const navWidth = window.getComputedStyle(navProperty, null).getPropertyValue('width'); 
  //const boxProperty = document.getElementById('boxPosition');
  if (navWidth === '0px') { 
       // Open sidenavbar               
       document.getElementById('subTitleSideNav').style.width = '140px'; 
       this.titleID = id; 
       //console.log(boxProperty);            
     } 
  }
```